# Jqgrid: Adding a column filter with multiselect checkboxes with and ok button just like excel data filter

Tags: jqgrid

I have a Jqgrid implementation which has a column filter with checkbox list. It works as expected but the problem is it triggers the search on every check/uncheck of the values in the checkbox list in the column filter. what I want is to let user check/uncheck as many values he/she wants and then have a "ok" button to trigger the search just like the image :[Excel Implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1hef.png)

Answer (score 0):

autosearch should be set to false and use triggerToolbar() when you presse the button.